# Aligning equations with two equal signs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am trying to write three equations, second with two equal signs. I would like the first two to be aligned by the first equal sign, and the second and third by the second equal sign. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\ddn}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} #1 } #2 }
\newcommand{\ddt}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t } }

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
x'(t)&=&\ddt\left(\left[-\frac{M}{\omega^2}\cos{(\omega t)}+B_1\sin{(\omega t)}\right]+
\left[\frac{M}{\omega^2}-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}t\right]\right)\\
{}&=&\frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega t)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega t)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}\\
\therefore x'(0) &=&
\frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega 0)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega 0)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}=0\\
\therefore B_1\omega-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

which produces following output:
[image: Original result]

Equations (1), (2), and (3) are aligned as desired, but I wish (4) to be aligned with the second equal sign in (3). Is that feasible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `eqnarray` is outdated, use `align` or a similar environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve this alignment, I would use `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap`, but I would use these in conjunction with the `alignat` environment, to ensure the proper alignment of `=` symbols on each line.

**Example code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmathm,amssymb}

\newcommand{\ddn}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}#1}#2}
\newcommand{\ddt}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}}

\begin{document}
% Start an equation environment with two sets of aligned equalities
\begin{alignat}{2}
    x'(t) &=
    % RHS "overlaps" anything on its right (occupies no space to its right)
    \mathrlap{\ddt\left(
        \left[-\frac{M}{\omega^2}\cos{(\omega t)}+B_1\sin{(\omega t)}\right] + 
        \left[\frac{M}{\omega^2}-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}t\right]
    \right)}
    % Add a little bit of space on the RHS in the second set of equalities, for balance
    &&\mspace{120mu}
    % Start a new line of the equation but without adding any equation numbers
    \notag\\
    &= \frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega t)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega t)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}
    % New line and equation number, with some added vertical space
    \\[1.5ex]
    \therefore x'(0) &=
    \frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega 0)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega 0)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}
    % Second set of equalities
    &&= 0
    % New line and new equation number, with some added vertical space
    \\[1.5ex]
    % Align the new equation at the second set of equalities; LHS "overlaps" anything
    % on its left so that it doesn't push away the second `=' in the previous equation
    && \mathllap{\therefore B_1\omega-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}} &= 0
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

**Example output:**

[image: Output for alignment at multiple ` symbols using the "alignat" environment]

Answer (score 1):

Still another possibility: I would *center* the final equation rather than align its `=` symbol with the one on the preceding line. To enhance the visual impact, I would also increase the vertical offset between equations (3) and (4).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand{\ddn}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} #1 } #2 }
\newcommand{\ddt}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t } }

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x'(t)&=\ddt\left(\left[-\frac{M}{\omega^2}\cos{(\omega t)}+B_1\sin{(\omega t)}\right]+
\left[\frac{M}{\omega^2}-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}t\right]\right)\\
{}&=\frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega t)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega t)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}\\
x'(0) &= \frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega 0)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega 0)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}=0\\[2ex]
&\qquad\qquad\quad\therefore B_1\omega-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}= 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest still another variant, also with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\ddn}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} #1 } #2 }
\newcommand{\ddt}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t } }

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  x'(t) & = \mathrlap{\ddt\left(\left[-\frac{M}{ω^2}\cos{(ω t)}+B_1\sin{(ω t)}\right]+
  \left[\frac{M}{ω^2}-\frac{M}{Tω^2}t\right]\right)} \\
    & \therefore{} & x'(t){} & = \frac{M}{ω}\sin{(ω t)}+B_1ω \cos{(ω t)}-\frac{M}{T ω^2} \\
    & \therefore{} & x'(0){} & {}=
  \frac{M}{ω}\sin{(ω 0)}+B_1ω \cos{(ω 0)}-\frac{M}{T ω^2} =0\\
  &\therefore{}\mathrlap{B_1\omega-\frac{M}{Tω^2} = 0}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically recommend a different alignment than that asked for by the OP? This doesn't look too bad, but it is basically just left-aligning everything after Eqn.(1), and arbitrarily doing so at the equality symbol of Eqn.(1).

Comment: It' only that it looks better, my opinion. It's not really a recommendation, just a suggestion. You didn't notice it, but the two `=` signs of eqs 2 and 3are also designed to be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the amsmath package and \begin{align} / \end{align} set for a tighter look.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\ddn}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} #1 } #2 }
\newcommand{\ddt}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t } }

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x'(t)&=\ddt\left(\left[-\frac{M}{\omega^2}\cos{(\omega t)}+B_1\sin{(\omega t)}\right]+
\left[\frac{M}{\omega^2}-\frac{M}{T\omega^2}t\right]\right) \\
&=\frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega t)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega t)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2} \\
\therefore x'(0) 
&=
\frac{M}{\omega}\sin{(\omega 0)}+B_1\omega\cos{(\omega 0)}-\frac{M}{T \omega^2}=0 \\
& \hspace{34mm} \therefore B_1\omega-\frac{M}{T\omega^2} = 0
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably revise your answer so that it compiles. But what about the alignment asked for by the OP?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Where may I find the information needed to correct the code so that it does compile on site?

Comment: It doesn't compile on the site: users compile it locally and upload images of the compiled result. So you should check that your code compiles on *your* computer. (I would recommend that if you're posting something that looks like a complete document, that it include the `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` as well!)

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Thanks for the help. Cut and pasting is great as long as the obvious is not missed. begin/end{document} is essential.

Comment: An image of the output would be helpful for viewers to determine whether copy and pasting this code will produce something they desire.