# Align equal sign in a big block of equations

Tags: equations, align

I would like to align the equal signs in this block of equations. Somehow, the first equal sign is well aligned, but the second is not. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you very much

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace 
\begin{aligned}
u_0 &=p_0 \\ 
u_1 &=p_0+p_1&=u_0+p_1  \\
u_2 &=p_0+p_1+p_2&=u_1+p_2  \\
\vdots \\
u_{n-1} &=p_0+p_1+\dots + p_{n-1} &= u_{n-2}+p_{n-1}  \\
u_{n} &=p_0+p_1+\dots + p_{n} &= u_{n-1}+p_{n}  \\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this might also be helpful: [Aligning equations with two equal signs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237815/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `alignedat`.  In contrast to `aligned` you have to specify the number of column pairs there, i.e. `\begin{alignedat}{2}`.  Also ever third column is right aligned so you need to insert an empty column before your second equals as in `&&=`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
      u_0 &=p_0 \\ 
      u_1 &=p_0+p_1&&=u_0+p_1  \\
      u_2 &=p_0+p_1+p_2&&=u_1+p_2  \\
      \vdots \\
      u_{n-1} &=p_0+p_1+\dots + p_{n-1} &&= u_{n-2}+p_{n-1}  \\
      u_{n} &=p_0+p_1+\dots + p_{n} &&= u_{n-1}+p_{n}  \\
    \end{alignedat}
  \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]